# SSRS - Display customer name in header based on body tablix current customer info

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012, ssrs-tablix

I have a Tablix that contains data per customer. Every page in my report contains data specific to the current customer.

So page1 has data for customer 1 in my data set and page 2 has data for customer 2 in my dataset.

I have a textbox in my report header which I want to populate with the customer name corresponding to the current customer data being shown in the tablix in the body.

the problem is I am only getting the First customer name in the header textbox so even if i switch pages in my report and am showing the data for customer 3 in the body, the header textbox will not change and will continue to show the name of customer 1.

I am not displaying the customer name in the body tablix by design. I know if I was displaying the customer name in the tablix I could just reference that textbox, in the header textbox but that is not the case in my scenario.

I know I could just add a hidden textbox that contains the customer name in the body tablix and then reference that textbox in my header textbox but that seems like more of a sloppy work around....

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

You need to refer to the value of the cell that contains the Customer name

```
 =ReportItems!customer_name.Value
```

Where `customer_name` is the name of the cell that displays the customer name on every page. To find the correct name, click on the cell that holds the customer name and look at the properties.

This will require you to have the customer name in a field and be hidden if you don't want to show it (yes it is sloppy)